# Issue creating URL Connection with the url having "%E2%80%93"

Tags: java, utf-8, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to download file from the following URL
[File URL](https://www.hse.ie/eng/services/list/5/cancer/profinfo/chemoprotocols/lymphoma-myeloma/549-obinutuzumab-and-chop-therapy-%E2%80%93-21-day.pdf). The problem is when I try to read anything from open connection like header or stream, the Unescape(%e2%80%93) character in URL get replace by junk. following is my code sample.

```
String url = "https://www.hse.ie/eng/services/list/5/cancer/profinfo/chemoprotocols/lymphoma-myeloma/549-obinutuzumab-and-chop-therapy-%E2%80%93-21-day.pdf";
URL webURL = new URL(URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8"));
HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) webURL.openConnection();
httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
System.out.println("URL Before Checking Response Code : " + httpUrlConnection.getURL().toString());
System.out.println("Response Code : " + httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode());
System.out.println("URL After Checking Response Code : " + httpUrlConnection.getURL().toString());
```

The output in console is as follows

```
URL Before Checking Response Code : https://www.hse.ie/eng/services/list/5/cancer/profinfo/chemoprotocols/lymphoma-myeloma/549-obinutuzumab-and-chop-therapy-–-21-day.pdf

Response Code : 400

URL After Checking Response Code : https://www.hse.ie/eng/services/list/5/cancer/profinfo/chemoprotocols/lymphoma-myeloma/549-obinutuzumab-and-chop-therapy-ÃÂ£ÃâÃÂ¢ÃâÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢ÃâÃÂ£ÃâÃÂ¢Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢ÃÂ£ÃÂ£ÃâÃÂ¢ÃâÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ£ÃâÃÂ¢Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢ÃÂ¢ÃÂ£ÃâÃÂ¢ÃâÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢ÃâÃÂ£ÃâÃÂ¢Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢ÃÂ¢ÃÂ£ÃâÃÂ¢ÃâÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢ÃÂ¢ÃÂ£ÃâÃÂ¢ÃÂ¢ÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢Ã¢âÂ¬ÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢ÃÂ¡ÃÂ£ÃâÃÂ¢Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢ÃÂ¬ÃÂ£ÃâÃÂ¢ÃâÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢ÃâÃÂ£ÃâÃÂ¢Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢ÃÂ¢ÃÂ£ÃâÃÂ¢ÃâÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢ÃÂ¢ÃÂ£ÃâÃÂ¢ÃÂ¢ÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢ÃÂ¬ÃÂ£ÃâÃÂ¢Ã¢â¬Â¦ÃÂ£Ã¢â¬Å¡ÃÂ¢Ã¢â¬Å-21-day.pdf
```

Comment: You should not be using URLDecoder at all.  Non-ASCII characters are not allowed in URLs.  `%E2%80%93` is the correct way to embed an en-dash character in a URL.  Note that URLDecoder, despite the name, is not for altering URLs;  it’s for application/x-www-url-encoded HTTP request bodies which were submitted from HTML forms.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace UTF-8 by ISO-8859-1 or
try to replace % by there html  code % or %25 or   % or
try to put your URL on textfild and set the font arial

Comment: The issue is not with encoding as I updated my question with outputs. Encoding seems to be work fine but issue is rather occur after i try to read content.